# Foreign key relationship with boolean values

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a feature. I've three different car types (Sedan, Hatchback, SUV):

```
Category(models.Model):
    id-
    name-
    image-
```

I've 6 features in total.

```
Feature(models.Model):
    id-
    name-
    detail-
    image-
```

Out of 6, 4 features are their in every car. The second car category has 5 and the third has all the 6 features. Here where I'm getting stuck:
I've to send all the 6 features in all the categories to the frontend so that if someone clicks on the first category, they should be able to show them all 6 with 2 non-available feature strike down or disabled or something. So basically there should be some boolean value which shows that this feature in this category is True or False.

How can I design the tables?

Comment: The "availability of a feature for a category" is formally a property of the M:N relationship between those two *strong* entities (category and feature). You'll need to add  a third table to hold this property as a weak entity that represents the many-to-many relationship between them.

Comment: @TheImpaler Could you please elaborate a bit. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a n:m Many to many relationship is represented as bridge table

And this would look like(the modes are shortend)

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)


class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='CategoryFeature')


class CategoryFeature(models.Model):
    feature= models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: This looks good. In this model, the sole presence of a row in `CategoryFeature` indicates that a feature is available for a category. If there ware more properties (since_when, until_when, region, subcategory, etc.) then the weak entity would need to include those extra properties as well.

Comment: yes, this is a normal table where you can add more information to that relationship, but keep normalization in mind, there should only be additional information for that relationship